# Getting A Link below footer - Want to remove it. How?

Tags: footer

My blog http://MyTechFlow.Com showing a link in urdu language after footer(below footer). 
I had tried to remove it by looking up into footer.php
But unable to find something... 
So guyz plz help me to fix it.
Here is the Screenshot:

http://share.pho.to/4RtoD/t1/original

Comment: Is this showing up recently or is this part of the theme credit?

Comment: It Starts Showing Recently.

Comment: Have you installed any plugins recently, or changed themes? If not, it is starting to sound like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Search all your theme and plugin PHP files for the string "wp_footer". Adding this as an action hook to a function allows themes and plug-ins to insert code at the bottom of the footer (without modifying footer.php.)

Notepad++ can do a multi-text-file search, as can gerpWin.

Comment: Plz Explain....

Comment: Hey, sorry I wasn't clear. Could you be more specific about what I need to explain better?